# Liferay ehcache clustering

Tags: jboss, liferay, cluster-computing, liferay-6, ehcache

I'm trying to setup clustering for my lifery 6.2 running on two JBoss 7.2. Both of my application servers use the same configuration but don't behave the same. One is starting and running fine, the other one crashes during startup. It's related to the cluster settings.

```
cluster.link.enabled=true
cluster.link.autodetect.address=10.170.121.184:1531
# second points to db server
```

As mentioned both servers use this setting. Once I remove those lines, the second server starts as well. But this would prevent me from using a clustered environment. I did some research in my logfiles and found several exceptions (during liferay deployment while server starts).

This is from liferays logfile. Not really exciting since it does not really provide valuable information.

```
12:11:53,259 INFO  [ServerService Thread Pool -- 127][LiferayCacheManagerPeerProviderFactory:76] portalPropertyKey ehcache.multi.vm.config.location.peerProviderProperties has value file=/usr/jboss/liferay-6.1/cluster-config-unicast.xml
12:18:12,793 ERROR [ServerService Thread Pool -- 127][PortalContextLoaderListener:132] java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.DirectServletRegistryUtil.clearServlets(DirectServletRegistryUtil.java:27)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:3427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:3920)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3839)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
12:18:12,795 ERROR [ServerService Thread Pool -- 127][PortalContextLoaderListener:139] java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil.reset(HotDeployUtil.java:53)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:3427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:3920)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3839)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
```

But this is where it gets interesting. This log file excerpt is from jboss log during startup (same time).

```
12:11:46,822 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 127) JBAS018210: Register web context: 
12:11:47,832 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 127) Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
12:18:12,760 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 127) JBWEB000287: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.kernel.cache.MultiVMPool' defined in class path resource [META-INF/util-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'com.liferay.portal.kernel.cache.MultiVMPortalCacheManager' while setting bean property 'portalCacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.kernel.cache.MultiVMPortalCacheManager' defined in class path resource [META-INF/util-spring.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'com.liferay.portal.cache.ehcache.EhcachePortalCacheManager#26eb6935' of type [com.liferay.portal.cache.ehcache.EhcachePortalCacheManager] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.cache.ehcache.EhcachePortalCacheManager#26eb6935' defined in class path resource [META-INF/util-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Problem starting listener for RMICachePeer //15.131.81.31:53440/com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.EntityCache.com.liferay.portal.model.impl.ResourcePermissionImpl. Initial cause was Connection refused to host: 15.131.81.31; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1327) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1085) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895) [spring-context.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425) [spring-context.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282) [spring-web.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204) [spring-web.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47) [spring-web.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:233) [portal-impl.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.kernel.cache.MultiVMPortalCacheManager' defined in class path resource [META-INF/util-spring.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'com.liferay.portal.cache.ehcache.EhcachePortalCacheManager#26eb6935' of type [com.liferay.portal.cache.ehcache.EhcachePortalCacheManager] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.cache.ehcache.EhcachePortalCacheManager#26eb6935' defined in class path resource [META-INF/util-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Problem starting listener for RMICachePeer //15.131.81.31:53440/com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.EntityCache.com.liferay.portal.model.impl.ResourcePermissionImpl. Initial cause was Connection refused to host: 15.131.81.31; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:120) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:630) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:441) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:982) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:878) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:484) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.cache.ehcache.EhcachePortalCacheManager#26eb6935' defined in class path resource [META-INF/util-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Problem starting listener for RMICachePeer //15.131.81.31:53440/com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.EntityCache.com.liferay.portal.model.impl.ResourcePermissionImpl. Initial cause was Connection refused to host: 15.131.81.31; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 40 more
Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Problem starting listener for RMICachePeer //15.131.81.31:53440/com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.EntityCache.com.liferay.portal.model.impl.ResourcePermissionImpl. Initial cause was Connection refused to host: 15.131.81.31; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListener.notifyCacheAdded(RMICacheManagerPeerListener.java:538) [ehcache.jar:]
    at net.sf.ehcache.event.CacheManagerEventListenerRegistry.notifyCacheAdded(CacheManagerEventListenerRegistry.java:159) [ehcache.jar:]
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.addCacheNoCheck(CacheManager.java:1408) [ehcache.jar:]
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.addConfiguredCaches(CacheManager.java:798) [ehcache.jar:]
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.doInit(CacheManager.java:485) [ehcache.jar:]
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:392) [ehcache.jar:]
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:266) [ehcache.jar:]
    at com.liferay.portal.cache.ehcache.CacheManagerUtil.createCacheManager(CacheManagerUtil.java:38) [portal-impl.jar:]
    at com.liferay.portal.cache.ehcache.EhcachePortalCacheManager.afterPropertiesSet(EhcachePortalCacheManager.java:77) [portal-impl.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1546) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1487) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419) [spring-beans.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 15.131.81.31; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:601) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:198) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:184) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:322) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Naming.java:160) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListener.bind(RMICacheManagerPeerListener.java:234) [ehcache.jar:]
    at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListener.notifyCacheAdded(RMICacheManagerPeerListener.java:536) [ehcache.jar:]
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:189) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:22) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:128) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:595) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    ... 65 more

12:18:12,774 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 127) JBWEB001103: Error detected during context  start, will stop it
12:18:12,796 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 127) Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
12:18:12,816 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 127) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:161)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93)
    ... 7 more

12:18:13,062 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS018559: Deployed "liferay-marketplace-portlet.war" (runtime-name : "marketplace-portlet.war")
12:18:13,063 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS018559: Deployed "liferay-portal-6.2-ee-sp7-20140807114015311.war" (runtime-name : "liferay-portal-6.2-ee-sp7-20140807114015311.war")
12:18:13,066 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context

12:18:13,070 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.2.0.Final "Janus" started (with errors) in 405064ms - Started 1695 of 1814 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 115 services are passive or on-demand)
```

Those two lines (from above jboss excerpt) are suspicious to me.

```
Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Problem starting listener for RMICachePeer //15.131.81.31:53440/com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.EntityCache.com.liferay.portal.model.impl.ResourcePermissionImpl. Initial cause was Connection refused to host: 15.131.81.31; nested exception is: 
    ...
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 15.131.81.31; nested exception is:
```

I don't know why this liferay tries to open a connection to this IP, I don't know where this address is configured (never did this by myself), I don't know to which system this address belongs to (not an IP from my network) and I don't know why my other server (with same config) is not running into such problems. Maybe this address is some sort of default or fallback?

This behavior does not change when I start the troublesome server first or completely alone. This one always runs into the given problem.

I do have some additional ehcache settings referenced in portal-ext.properties to use unicasts instead of multicasts, but this config is the same for both servers too so the initial cause must be somewhere else. But maybe I could use these additional ehcache settings to adjust this IP?

I followed one of liferays blog entries to set up my environment. As of now my ehcache settings are the same as mentioned in this post (since my second server is not starting I cannot check whether I need some changes).
https://www.liferay.com/de/web/fimez/blog/-/blogs/configuring-a-liferay-cluster-and-make-it-use-unicast-

Does anyone have some expirience with setting up a liferay 6.2 cluster or maybe some insight on ehcache/jgroups settings that could turn out helpful? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Seems to be answered [here](https://www.liferay.com/de/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/41898981).

Answer (score 1):

I'm in a pretty similar scenario, using Liferay 6.2 running on two JBoss 6.3, and same as you "Both of my application servers use the same configuration but don't behave the same. One is starting and running fine, the other one crashes during startup."

After testing a lot of configurations, this one work for me, I removed this line from the server which runs into the given problem:

```
cluster.link.enabled=true
```

Leaving the line just in the server which is starting fine.

Surprisingly cluster configuration works very well.

PD. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Following must be the problem.....

> Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 15.131.81.31; nested exception is: 
>       java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out

This is maybe because of the firewall configuration. Or because of other network related causes... Or the expected service,- RMI serice is not running at 15.131.81.31

Once this is sorted out.... I hope you could come out of the problem....